# How to control tracking options and tags when using Mailgun's SMTP option (i.e. not using their API)

Tags: tags, smtp, tracking, mailgun

I’m using python to send emails using Mailgun’s SMTP server. I wish to use Mailgun’s builtin ability to tag my messages, and to track open and click events.

I know this can be done using Mailgun’s send message API, by adding headers like o:tag, o:tracking, o:tracking-clicks and o:tracking-opens (as explained here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending)

However, seeing as I'm the SMTP gateway and not the API, I’m trying to understand how to achieve the same result - emails that are tagged and fully tracked in Mailgun.

Any thoughts on how it can be done?

This is my little script at the moment:

```
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "This is an email"
message["From"] = “<from email>”
message["To"] = “<to email>”
htmlpart = MIMEText("<html><body>email here!</body></html>", "html")
message.attach(htmlpart)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(“<smtp server>”, 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(“<username>”, “<password>”)
server.sendmail(from_addr=“<from email>”, to_addrs=“<to email>”, msg=message.as_string())
server.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

The following X-Mailgun headers can be added:
https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-smtp

So my script would be:

```
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "This is an email"
message["From"] = “<from email>”
message["To"] = “<to email>”
message["X-Mailgun-Tag"] = "<tag>"
message["X-Mailgun-Track"] = "yes"
message["X-Mailgun-Track-Clicks"] = "yes"
message["X-Mailgun-Track-Opens"] = "yes"
htmlpart = MIMEText("<html><body>email here!</body></html>", "html")
message.attach(htmlpart)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(“<smtp server>”, 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(“<username>”, “<password>”)
server.sendmail(from_addr=“<from email>”, to_addrs=“<to email>”, msg=message.as_string())
server.close()
```

Now my email is tagged (can be analysed on a tag level in Mailgun), and clicks are tracked.

Happy days!